# Google Directions Json Error

Tags: objective-c, json

I'm trying to get the directions using google directions but I'm getting this error :

> Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Unrecognised
>   leading character (41)\

Here is the Json

`loadDirections('Avenida Paulista', 'Rua Augusta', { 'locale': 'en', travelMode: G_TRAVEL_MODE_WALKING, avoidHighways: false, getPolyline: true, getSteps: true, preserveViewport: false})`

Whats is wrong? Whats *Unrecognised leading character (41)* mean?

```
 - (void)loadWithStartPoint:(NSString *)startPoint endPoint:(NSMutableArray *)endPoints options:(UICGDirectionsOptions *)options {
for (int idx = 0; idx < [endPoints count];idx ++) 
{
    NSString* msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"loadDirections('%@', '%@', %@)", startPoint, [endPoints objectAtIndex:idx], [options JSONRepresentation]];
    NSLog(@"msg %@",msg);
    mstr = [msg retain];
    [self performSelector:@selector(loadDirections:)  withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
}
}
 -(void)loadDirections:(NSString *)message
{
[googleMapsAPI stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:mstr];
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The JSON is invalid.

```
{ 
  'locale': 'en', 
  travelMode: "G_TRAVEL_MODE_WALKING", 
  avoidHighways: false, 
  getPolyline: true, 
  getSteps: true, 
  preserveViewport: false
}
```

I think this has something to do with G_TRAVEL_MODE_WALKING, it should be in quotes. The only valid JSON values are as follows

- Objects (`{}`)
- Arrays (`[]`)
- Value

  - String (`"this is a string"`)
  - Number `1/-1`
  - `true`
  - `false`
  - `null`

[JSON Documentation](http://www.json.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that, while initializing the GDirections object, you also pass an actual element as the second parameter.

As stated in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference?hl=en#GDirections):

> The mode of travel, such as driving (default) or walking. Note that if
>   you specify walking directions, you will need to specify a  panel
>   to hold a warning notice to users.

If you are using the [Map-Kit-Route-Directions extensions](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/MapKit-Route-Directions), you just have to open the **api.html** file and, at line 16, substitute this

```
gdir = new GDirections(null, null);
```

with this

```
gdir = new GDirections(null, "body");
```